# Appending to an array while looping

Tags: excel, vba

I've got the following:

```
Dim dupArray As Variant
dupArray = Array("dup")

For j = LBound(numArray) To UBound(numArray)
    
    If IsInArray(Range(numArray(j)).Text, dupArray) Then
        Range(numArray(j)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        MsgBox "Duplicate value"

    ElseIf IsInArray(Range(numArray(j)).Text, keyArray) Then
        Application.OnKey Range(numArray(j)).Text, comArray(j)
        ReDim Preserve dupArray(j)
        Dim cellEntry As String
        cellEntry = Range(numArray(j)).Text
        MsgBox cellEntry
        dupArray(j) = cellEntry
        
                
    Else
        Range(numArray(j)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        MsgBox "Unrecognized key code in " & numArray(j)
        End If
    Next j
```

In essence, I want VBA to read the contents of a cell and append them to an array for comparison. Code to read the contents of a cell is Range(numArray(j)).Text...  For some reason, cellEntry and dupArray(j) are not equal.  More specifically, for the cell A6, cellEntry is "b" (which is the correct contents), but dupArray(j) is "A6"... any thoughts?  There's no error code, it's just not putting the correct value in the array.

Thank you!

(Edit) Code for Function IsInArray:

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))
End Function
```

(Edit 2) Don't pay attention to much else... I'm just wondering why cellEntry doesn't match dupArray(j) for all values of j when they should clearly be the same thing.

Comment: Could you share the code of the `IsInArray` function? What is the reason behind you using `.Text` instead of `.Value` or `.Value2`? This whole operation looks like it could be easier done using a dictionary or a collection. Please, add more detail to your post (e.g. regarding `Application.OnKey`).

Comment: @VBasic2008, yep done!  I'm sure there's an easier way to do this... I'm pretty competent in R and Python but I'm really struggling in VBA.  Granted, .Value works too in Application.OnKey

Comment: `Dim dupArray` inside loop, why ? How are you inspecting the content of `dupArray(j) `

Comment: @CDP1802 mistake. fixed code

Comment: Put   `MsgBox cellEntry, dupArray(j)` after `dupArray(j) = cellEntry`

Comment: You are redimming `dupArray` up to the current `j` each time even though on several previous values of `j` there might have not been any redims. This creates gaps in `dupArray`. Is it why you cannot then locate your value where you expect?

Comment: Your code seems to work, but it depends on `keyArray` being populated.  Some sample data, expected results, and contents of `keyArray` would help us help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work, but it depends on `keyArray` being populated.

I've run this demo code, including populating `numArray` and `keyArray` with test values, to illustrate what happens.

If how I've populated these arrays doesn't match your code, please add that info to your Q.

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim dupArray As Variant
    Dim numArray As Variant
    Dim keyArray As Variant
    Dim comArray As Variant
    Dim j As Long
    
    ' for testing
    numArray = Application.Transpose([A1:A6].Value)
    ReDim keyArray(1 To 3)
    keyArray(1) = "x"
    keyArray(2) = "a"
    keyArray(3) = "s"
    
    dupArray = Array("dup")
    
    For j = LBound(numArray) To UBound(numArray)
        If IsInArray(Range(numArray(j)).Text, dupArray) Then
            Range(numArray(j)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            'MsgBox "Duplicate value"
    
        ElseIf IsInArray(Range(numArray(j)).Text, keyArray) Then
            'Application.OnKey Range(numArray(j)).Text, comArray(j)
            ReDim Preserve dupArray(j)
            Dim cellEntry As String
            cellEntry = Range(numArray(j)).Text
            'MsgBox cellEntry
            dupArray(j) = cellEntry
            
                    
        Else
            Range(numArray(j)).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 ' changed to be distinct for testing
            'MsgBox "Unrecognized key code in " & numArray(j)
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

Sheet, before

[image]

Sheet, after

[image]

Variable values at end of execution

[image]

As you can see, `dupArray` has been populated sparsley, in line with `numArray`.  This is fine for how it's used with `IsInArray`.  If it's used for something else too, you can change how it's populated.

Comment: Thank you!  I spent a ton of time trying to debug yesterday and honestly have no clue what happened.  I think that the ```Dim cellEntry As String``` was the key to getting it to work.